# Spark and Hbase Integration version compatibility?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, hbase

I am trying to integrate Spark 3.2  with Hbase 2.0. I am currently using hadoop 3.2.2. Can somebody tell me which version of Hbase is compatible with Spark 3.2?

Comment: What are you using for connecting Spark to HBase? The official HBase Spark connector got updated recently and no longer compiles against HBase versions lower than 2.4.

Comment: I'm using pyspark for integration. trying to integrate as in the below url
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73160842/how-to-integrate-hbase-with-spark-using-python
after some research i found it's versioning issue but not aware what exactly the compatible versions